# Where do the accessible variables come in in e-mail marketing templates?

Tags: magento2, email-templates, order-email

In normal templates it is possible to know which class is being loaded through xml and in this way it is possible to overwrite classes and methods by creating modules. We can even add new methods.

But I could not easily find how email marketing templates carry these variables.

Here is an example:

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

<table>
    <tr class="email-intro">
        <td>
            <p class="greeting">{{trans "%customer_name," customer_name=$order.getCustomerName()}}</p>
            <p>
                {{trans "Thank you for your order from %store_name." store_name=$store.getFrontendName()}}
                {{trans "Once your package ships we will send you a tracking number."}}
                {{trans 'You can check the status of your order by <a href="%account_url">logging into your account</a>.' account_url=$this.getUrl($store,'customer/account/',[_nosid:1]) |raw}}
            </p>
            <p>
                {{trans 'If you have questions about your order, you can email us at <a href="mailto:%store_email">%store_email</a>' store_email=$store_email |raw}}{{depend store_phone}} {{trans 'or call us at <a href="tel:%store_phone">%store_phone</a>' store_phone=$store_phone |raw}}{{/depend}}.
                {{depend store_hours}}
                    {{trans 'Our hours are <span class="no-link">%store_hours</span>.' store_hours=$store_hours |raw}}
                {{/depend}}
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="email-summary">
        <td>
            <h1>{{trans 'Your Order <span class="no-link">#%increment_id</span>' increment_id=$order.increment_id |raw}}</h1>
            <p>{{trans 'Placed on <span class="no-link">%created_at</span>' created_at=$order.getCreatedAtFormatted(2) |raw}}</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="email-information">
        <td>
            {{depend order.getEmailCustomerNote()}}
            <table class="message-info">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {{var order.getEmailCustomerNote()|escape|nl2br}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            {{/depend}}
            <table class="order-details">
                <tr>
                    <td class="address-details">
                        <h3>{{trans "Billing Info"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var formattedBillingAddress|raw}}</p>
                    </td>
                    {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                    <td class="address-details">
                        <h3>{{trans "Shipping Info"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var formattedShippingAddress|raw}}</p>
                    </td>
                    {{/depend}}
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="method-info">
                        <h3>{{trans "Payment Method"}}</h3>
                        {{var payment_html|raw}}
                    </td>
                    {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                    <td class="method-info">
                        <h3>{{trans "Shipping Method"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var order.getShippingDescription()}}</p>
                        {{if shipping_msg}}
                        <p>{{var shipping_msg}}</p>
                        {{/if}}
                    </td>
                    {{/depend}}
                </tr>
            </table>
            {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order area="frontend"}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

Where does $order come from?

The xml below does not load any class just the template.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="sales_email_order_template" label="New Order" file="order_new.phtml" type="html" module="Ahimsa_Sales" area="frontend"/>
    <template id="sales_email_order_guest_template" label="New Order for Guest" file="order_new_guest.html" type="html" module="Magento_Sales" area="frontend"/>
    <template id="sales_email_order_comment_template" label="Order Update" file="order_update.html" type="html" module="Magento_Sales" area="frontend"/>
    <template id="sales_email_order_comment_guest_template" label="Order Update for Guest" file="order_update_guest.html" type="html" module="Magento_Sales" area="frontend"/>
    <template id="sales_email_invoice_template" label="New Invoice" file="invoice_new.html" type="html" module="Magento_Sales" area="frontend"/>
    <template id="sales_email_invoice_guest_template" label="New Invoice for Guest" file="invoice_new_guest.html" type="html" module="Magento_Sales" area="frontend"/>
    <template id="sales_email_invoice_comment_template" label="Invoice Update" file="invoice_update.html" type="html" module="Magento_Sales" area="frontend"/>
    <template id="sales_email_invoice_comment_guest_template" label="Invoice Update for Guest" file="invoice_update_guest.html" type="html" module="Magento_Sales" area="frontend"/>
    <template id="sales_email_creditmemo_template" label="New Credit Memo" file="creditmemo_new.html" type="html" module="Magento_Sales" area="frontend"/>
    <template id="sales_email_creditmemo_guest_template" label="New Credit Memo for Guest" file="creditmemo_new_guest.html" type="html" module="Magento_Sales" area="frontend"/>
    <template id="sales_email_creditmemo_comment_template" label="Credit Memo Update" file="creditmemo_update.html" type="html" module="Magento_Sales" area="frontend"/>
    <template id="sales_email_creditmemo_comment_guest_template" label="Credit Memo Update for Guest" file="creditmemo_update_guest.html" type="html" module="Magento_Sales" area="frontend"/>
    <template id="sales_email_shipment_template" label="New Shipment" file="shipment_new.html" type="html" module="Magento_Sales" area="frontend"/>
    <template id="sales_email_shipment_guest_template" label="New Shipment for Guest" file="shipment_new_guest.html" type="html" module="Magento_Sales" area="frontend"/>
    <template id="sales_email_shipment_comment_template" label="Shipment Update" file="shipment_update.html" type="html" module="Magento_Sales" area="frontend"/>
    <template id="sales_email_shipment_comment_guest_template" label="Shipment Update for Guest" file="shipment_update_guest.html" type="html" module="Magento_Sales" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

So how to add new variables, new methods?